# HttpWebRequest accept 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

This is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

WebResponse wr = req.GetResponse();
```

When the server returns 500 Internal Server Error, exception is thrown in req.GetResponse().
I would like the GetResponse() to accept this Response Code, it is normal for the passed url to throw this Response Code. I would like to parse the Html despite Response Code 500 Internal Server Error. Is it possible to say to GetResponse() method not to verify the Response Code?

Comment: Your questions don't make sense to me. HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() does nothing special when it receives a 500 response code. You are free to parse the html that you receive.

Comment: You should use the new [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi @KeithPayne, GetResponse does throw an Exception if the response has Status=500 and you are not able to read the content. I just tried to apply the fix and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    WebResponse wr = req.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    var pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                          .ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: It allows the calling code to read the content on the response stream from the server, without the try and catch block this would not be possible.

Comment: If you put WebResponse wr = null; outside the try then in the catch you can check if wr is null and if not read the response status.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved with this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var soap = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:tem=""http://tempuri.org/""><s:Body><GetData xmlns = ""http://tempuri.org/""><value>2</value></GetData></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:51148/Service1.svc");

        req.Headers.Add($"SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData");
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";

        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soap);
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;

        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";

        Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream();
        stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        try
        {

            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
            using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```