# Suppression of WebException

Tags: c#, http, web, webclient, system.net.webexception

Is there a way to suppress the occurrence of WebException when the http status code is 500 in C # WebClient? WebException is created by StackTrace, which slows down the system. This is especially serious if WebExceptions occur frequently.

Comment: So your question isn't how to suppress `WebException`, it's actually asking if there's a way to get the response status code before the exception is thrown, right?

Comment: The performance impact of an exception being thrown is only really noticeable with a debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

There are many http clients, one of which is `WebClient`. WebClient is *designed* to throw exceptions. There is no way to have it *not* throw exceptions, as much as people would like.

Its predecessor, `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`, [also does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081726/why-does-httpwebrequest-throw-an-exception-instead-returning-httpstatuscode-notf).

If you don't want to catch the exception, you'll need to use another client.

`HttpClient` [doesn't throw exceptions based on the returned status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478328/http-clients-that-dont-throw-on-error), so that's an option.

You could use [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) as an alternative which [uses `HttpClient` under the hood](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/). Add the [error handling](https://flurl.dev/docs/error-handling/) method `.AllowHttpStatus("500")`.

Comment: Is there a way to see if the HttpClient or Flurl is using HttpWebRequest inside the module and is catching the exception inside the module so that the exception is not visible to the user?
If exceptions are caught internally, the problem of slowing down the system when http status code 500 occurs frequently will not be solved.

Comment: HttpClient and Flurl do not use HttpWebRequest, they use their own thing. They only throw exceptions if the connection failed.