# How to send a PUT request in xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, laravel, api, xamarin.android

I am trying to send a PUT request when a button is click from my xamarin.android application to update a record in my database with the following code:

I tried sending this json data using postman and it worked:

```
{'status': 'On'}
```

But when I tried sending this in my xamarin.android application it doesn't work.

Error: Remote server return an error (500) Internal server error

**Function:**

```
        private async void SendAPIRequest(string method, string jsonrequest)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest(new Uri(String.Format("http://192.168.0.179:8080/api/devices/update/1")));//address of request
            request.Method = "PUT";

            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(jsonrequest);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
            string json;
            using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                json = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();//read the Json and assign it to a variable
            }
        }
```

**Button Click**

```
        private void BtnRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string request = @"{'status': 'On'}";
            SendAPIRequest("PUT", request);
        }
```

PS: This only a test API so authentication is not required.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a sufficient error description. What do you see happening? Do you get any errors? Any response from the server?

Comment: Do you enable internet permission in manifest ?  Have you used `Try catch` to see what happened?

Comment: Please read edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use try catch to warp your code .

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    WebResponse wr = req.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    var pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                          .ReadToEnd();
}
```

Refer the smiliar case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403922/8187800 .